# Subsetting top 4 observations of each unique ID

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe of 4 columns and a few thousands rows. I am ordering the dataframe according to thier 4th column-which is their ID-(descending) then to the second column (ascending). Here's what my data looks like:

```
 X1 X2 X3 X4
 24  1 23 25
 21  3 19 25
 19  6 20 25
 11 12 14 25
 14  9 21 24
  3 12 25 24
 24 15 23 24
  8  1  4 23
 17  4 12 23
 16 11 23 23
 20 19 21 23
 24 19 16 23
 19 20  7 23
 19 22 22 22
 11  2 18 21
 15  9 19 21
 10 14  9 21
 17 15 19 21
 16 20  6 21
```

I am trying to keep the highest 4 values of each ID (if available), my desired output would be

```
 X1 X2 X3 X4
 24  1 23 25
 21  3 19 25
 19  6 20 25
 11 12 14 25
 14  9 21 24
  3 12 25 24
 24 15 23 24
  8  1  4 23
 17  4 12 23
 16 11 23 23
 20 19 21 23
 19 22 22 22
 11  2 18 21
 15  9 19 21
 10 14  9 21
 17 15 19 21
# note that 2 of the 23 ID observations and one of the 21 ID observations were removed.
```

I was wondering if there is there some short command that can do the job for me? I can think of a command that is around 1 page long! which is subsetting the data according to the 4th column, taking the top 5, then rbind them again. But that sounds so unprofessional!

Here's a command to generate similar example:

```
m0 <- matrix(0, 100, 4)
df <- data.frame(apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0:25),1)))
##fix(df)
odf <- df[order(-as.numeric(df$X4), as.numeric(df$X2)), ]
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I include your code again with a `set.seed` call, so that this is exactly reproducible.

```
set.seed(1)
m0 <- matrix(0, 100, 4)
df <- data.frame(apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0:25),1)))
odf <- df[order(-as.numeric(df$X4), as.numeric(df$X2)), ]
```

Here's the code you need using a **split-apply-combine** strategy:

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(odf, odf$X4), function(z) head(z[order(z$X2),],4) ))
out <- out[order(out$X4, decreasing=TRUE),]
```

Result:

```
> dim(out)
[1] 79  4
> head(out)
      X1 X2 X3 X4
25.24  3  4 13 25
25.6  23  5 13 25
25.19  9 11 24 25
25.40 10 13 11 25
24.93 16  2 25 24
24.26 10 11 13 24
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, so it is basically the same idea but, MUCH better scripting :) Appreciated.

Comment: Just converted this to a "dplyr" approach. Haven't used dplyr much, so not even sure if it's the best approach, but the solution I proposed is *fast*.

Comment: Thanks @AnandaMahto, I might need the fastest possible approach for this issue, the dataset is immense! I will read the details you have posted at your answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

maybe `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)

df<-read.table(header=T,text=" X1 X2 X3 X4
 24  1 23 25
 21  3 19 25
 19  6 20 25
 11 12 14 25
 14  9 21 24
  3 12 25 24
 24 15 23 24
  8  1  4 23
 17  4 12 23
 16 11 23 23
 20 19 21 23
 24 19 16 23
 19 20  7 23
 19 22 22 22
 11  2 18 21
 15  9 19 21
 10 14  9 21
 17 15 19 21
 16 20  6 21")

data.table(df)[,.SD[order(X2)][1:4,],by="X4"][!is.na(X3)][,list(X1,X2,X3,X4)]

   X1 X2 X3 X4
1: 24  1 23 25
2: 21  3 19 25
3: 19  6 20 25
4: 11 12 14 25
5: 14  9 21 24
6:  3 12 25 24
7: 24 15 23 24
8:  8  1  4 23
9: 17  4 12 23
10: 16 11 23 23
11: 20 19 21 23
12: 19 22 22 22
13: 11  2 18 21
14: 15  9 19 21
15: 10 14  9 21
16: 17 15 19 2
```

here's what's happening in the `data.table` call:

```
data.table(df)[         # data.table of df
  ,.SD[                 # for each by=X4, .SD is the sub-table
    order(X2)][1:4,],   # first four entries ordered by X2 
  by="X4"][             # X4 is the grouping variable
    !is.na(X3)][        # filter out NAs (i.e. less than 4 entries per row)
      ,list(X1,X2,X3,X4)] # order the columns
```

Comment: +1. Or better yet, bring the first order into `data.table` too: `data.table(df)[order(-X4)][,.SD[order(X2)][1:4,],by="X4"][!is.na(X3)][,list(X1,X2,X3,X4)]`

Answer (score 2):

I think that Thomas's solution is fine, but can be improved. I would guess that the splitting, recombining, and reordering might be time consuming.

Instead, I would create a vector from which we can subset.

This is easily done with `ave` and should work since the data are already ordered.

Continuing from:

```
odf <- df[order(-as.numeric(df$X4), as.numeric(df$X2)), ]
```

we can do:

```
out <- odf[ave(odf$X4, odf$X4, FUN = seq_along) <= 4, ]
head(out)
#    X1 X2 X3 X4
# 24  3  4 13 25
# 6  23  5 13 25
# 19  9 11 24 25
# 40 10 13 11 25
# 93 16  2 25 24
# 26 10 11 13 24

tail(out)
#    X1 X2 X3 X4
# 61 23  7 13  2
# 2   9  9  5  2
# 17 18 18 16  2
# 67 12  1  1  1
# 52 22 14 24  1
# 9  16 24  6  1
```

---

#### Update: New alternatives and benchmarks

The "dplyr" package would be great for this, and the syntax is pretty compact. But first, let's set some things up to see how fast these options are:

Functions to benchmark

```
fun1 <- function() {
  odf <- df[order(-as.numeric(df$X4), as.numeric(df$X2)), ]
  out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(odf, odf$X4), function(z) head(z[order(z$X2),],4) ))
  out[order(out$X4, decreasing=TRUE),]
}

fun2 <- function() {
  odf <- df[order(-as.numeric(df$X4), as.numeric(df$X2)), ]
  odf[ave(odf$X4, odf$X4, FUN = seq_along) <= 4, ]
}

fun3 <- function() {
  DT <- data.table(df)
  DT[, X := -X4]
  setkey(DT, X, X2)
  DT[, .SD[sequence(min(.N, 4))], by = X][, X:=NULL][]
}

fun4 <- function() {
  group_by(arrange(df, desc(X4), X2), X4) %.% 
    mutate(vals = seq_along(X4)) %.% 
    filter(vals <= 4)
}
```

A bigger version of your sample data

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1000, 1000000 * 4, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))
```

The necessary packages

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
```

The first two approaches (Thomas's and my first approach) take a fair amount of time, so instead of benchmarking, I'll just time them once.

```
system.time(fun1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   6.645   0.007   6.670 

system.time(fun2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.053   0.004   4.186
```

Here's the "dplyr" and "data.table" results.

```
microbenchmark(fun3(), fun4(), times = 20)
# Unit: seconds
#    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  fun3() 2.157956 2.221746 2.303286 2.343951 2.392391    20
#  fun4() 1.169212 1.180780 1.194994 1.206651 1.369922    20
```

Compare the output of the "dplyr" and "data.table" approaches:

```
out_DT <- fun3()
out_DP <- fun4()
out_DT
#        X1 X2  X3   X4
#    1: 340  0 708 1000
#    2: 144  1 667 1000
#    3:  73  2 142 1000
#    4:  79  2 826 1000
#    5: 169  0 870  999
#   ---                
# 4000:  46  4   2    1
# 4001:  88  0 809    0
# 4002: 535  0 522    0
# 4003:  75  3 234    0
# 4004: 983  3 492    0
head(out_DP, 5)
# Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
# Groups: X4
# 
#    X1 X2  X3   X4 vals
# 1 340  0 708 1000    1
# 2 144  1 667 1000    2
# 3  73  2 142 1000    3
# 4  79  2 826 1000    4
# 5 169  0 870  999    1
tail(out_DP, 5)
# Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
# Groups: X4
# 
#       X1 X2  X3 X4 vals
# 4000  46  4   2  1    4
# 4001  88  0 809  0    1
# 4002 535  0 522  0    2
# 4003  75  3 234  0    3
# 4004 983  3 492  0    4
```

Comment: +1 I suspect the reordering is the really time consuming part on my version and your first version. Have we run benchmarks on `order` anywhere else on SO?

Comment: @Thomas, `order` is definitely a bottleneck, and it becomes increasingly so when we have  a lot of values to order.